# scrollTop jumps when called multiple times on same item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I'm using jquery's scrollTop function and can't figure out why it jumps around when called multiple times on the same item.

I've put together this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wgqoh1b3/) to illustrate the problem. When the test button is clicked it alternates between scrolling to the item specified and to another location on the list.

```js
$('#button').click(function () {
$('.items').scrollTop($('li.8').offset().top);  // scroll to item 8
});
```

```css
.items{
    max-height: 80px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items large-8 columns end">
<ul class="list">
<li class="0">Almy, Joannie </li><li class="1">Auclair, Donnette </li><li class="2">Auerbach, Trinh </li><li class="3">Bement, Margeret </li><li class="4">Bryan, Willian </li><li class="5">Bullen, Tempie </li><li class="6">Coppa, Ozella </li><li class="7">Dahlin, Clementina</li><li class="8">Dahlman, Sasha </li><li class="9">Dorfman, Josef </li><li class="10">Heckert, Whitney </li><li class="11">Hendershott, Lida </li><li class="12">Holmes, Ellsworth </li><li class="13">Jaffee, Karlyn </li><li class="14">Joslyn, Nora </li><li class="15">Kiley, Patrica </li><li class="16">Lakes, Mickie </li><li class="17">Leiker, Enola</li><li class="18">Lemaire, Shanel, </li><li class="19">Lingerfelt, Graham </li><li class="20">Mangum, Maile </li><li class="21">Marcinkowski, Monica </li><li class="22">Mcraney, Allyson </li><li class="23">Meyerson, Lura </li><li class="24">Mole, Eboni </li><li class="25">Paulsen, Merrie </li><li class="26">Preble, Rivka </li><li class="27">Privette, Vonnie </li><li class="28">Quinones, Tilda </li><li class="29">Rojo, Eloy </li><li class="30">Semple, Dwana </li><li class="31">Sifuentes, Tyron </li><li class="32">Sloat, Dante </li><li class="33">Slocum, Shanna </li><li class="34">Sly, Ellamae </li><li class="35">Stolp, Courtney </li><li class="36">Till, Lucien </li><li class="37">Ulman, Jennifer </li><li class="38">Wadlow, Cassandra </li><li class="39">Zellars, Marty </li>
</ul>
</div>
<button id="button">test</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the item that you're getting the offset property, and offset returns the element position relative to document, which means when you scroll on your UL the li with class 8 offset changes and on this case you have to use position :

```
$('#button').click(function () {
$('.items').scrollTop($('li.8').position().top);  // scroll to item 8
});
```

In order to make it work properly parent should have position relative, you can check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wgqoh1b3/28/

Comment: When I test this it produces the same result

Comment: @Jess you have to make the parent ul position relative.

Comment: The edited version works flawlessly, thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

To make it stop jumping you can try the following code:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
   $('.items').scrollTop(0);
   $('.items').scrollTop($("li.8").position().top);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your suggestion, this worked best for me when combined with the suggestion of using position() instead of offset() above.

Jumping up to the top before jumping back down seems like a bit of a hack though, any other recommendations on getting this working properly?

Comment: To solve that problem you need to find out how to get the position of "li.8" relative to the container '.items' (e.g. how far from the beginning of the container/top is the position of your wanted element, counting as if it was a flat design).